# Remove spaces before getting the result in laravel elequent

Tags: php, laravel

i want to compare the search result in laravel controller.

When user input the name and search. In my controller it will remove the input spaces and compare data retrieved from database.

Users submitted is John Doe

```
preg_match_all('/\@([^\s\.]+)/', $request->name, $matches);
```

Remove spaces become JohnDoe. Then get data with

```
$user = User::where('name', $name)->first();
```

And i want remove the name column spaces before comparing the result. For example the data get from database column is John Doe. How to remove the spaces and comparing them.
`$user = User::where('John Doe', $matches)->first();`

Comment: Do you mean your db table column bears 'John Doe' or one of the values of 'name' column is 'John Doe'?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi  one of the values of 'name' column is 'John Doe'

Answer (score 2):

Well I would say:

1. There is a problem if you are saving a different data to the one you really need. I mean you can easily save JohnDoe and its easy, and also makes life easy.
2. You can use Raw sql query with `whereRaw()` method as such:

   ```
   User::whereRaw("REPLACE(`name`, ' ', '') = ? ", $name)->first();
   ```

The `REPLACE()` removes all whitespace and with no space. Find more about mysql `REPLACE()` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `whereRaw`:

```
$user = User::whereRaw("name REGEXP 'your_regex'")->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this methods could be work.

```
$user = User::where('name','%'.$name.'%')
                    ->orWhere('name','LIKE','%'.preg_replace('/\@([^\s\.]+)/', '', $name).'%')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did use `whereRaw`

`User::whereRaw("REPLACE('name', ' ', '') = ? ",  $request->name)->first();`

and also if you want to use `OR` you can use: `orWhereRaw`

`orWhereRaw` or `whereRaw` used to write SQL functions.